# PHP referring to object data with numerical key

Tags: php

I have converted an array to object data like this:

```
<?php
$myobject->data = (object)Array('zero','one','two');
print_r($myobject);
?>
```

And the output is:

> stdClass Object ( [data] => stdClass
>   Object ( [0] => zero [1] => one [2] =>
>   two ) )

So far so good. But if I try to refer to the numerical keys...

```
<?php
$myobject->data = (object)Array('zero','one','two');
$counter = 1;
echo $myobject->data->$counter;
?>
```

...nothing is returned! I would expect it to echo "one".

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's an oddity in PHP, you need to access it using `$object->data->{1}`. Or you could convert it back to array for accessing the members. But I think it is best to have proper names for object members, try something like this, for example:

```
$myobject->data = (object)Array('m0' => 'zero','m1' => 'one','m2' => 'two');
$myObject->data->m1;
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You could try accessing it as an array element. But I'm not sure whether that would work or not.</strike>
However, what you can do is looping over the object elements (or rather, properties) using a foreach loop.

Like so:

```
foreach ($myobject->data as $key => $value)
    echo "$key is my key.<br />";
```

I'm just not sure whether you can access the key, too.

Comment: Did you test this? I'd be interested in knowing whether it works. Else, just use soulmerge's solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is, that `$counter` is automatically converted to String for the look-up. Try

```
$myobject->$counter = "abc";
var_dump($myobject);
```

and you'll see what I mean. To circumvent this use the method Franz has proposed.

Answer (score -4):

```
echo $myobject->data[$counter];
```

If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: As long as the class doesn't implement ArrayAccess, you can't access it this way: http://de2.php.net/manual/de/class.arrayaccess.php